# Move DTC from one node to another in Windows 2003 R2 Clustering

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I have a Windows 2003 R2 two node cluster that is running MSDTC as part of the Cluster Group.  Is it possible for me to change the current MSDTC owner without moving the entire Cluster Group to the new owner?

It is my understanding if I run the following command I will move the entire Cluster Group to Node to and not only the MSDTC.

```
cluster group "Cluster Group" /move:Node2
```

I don't see anything under the cluster resource command [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785087%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) that allows me to change the resource owner.

Comment: Quick suggestion: Create another group and move it to that group? /move[to]:Group Then move group. Would that work for you?

Comment: Eric, I think it is going to have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only move groups, not individual services - if the msdtc has other resources in the same group, then they will need to move as well. To get around this, create a new clister group and include just the msdtc, then you're free to move it without impacting any other cluster resources or services.